# Fragment switching with AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-fragments

My apps uses fragments to show a ListView in portrait mode or the ListView and "details" view, side-by-side, in landscape mode.  I also have a menu item in the ActionBar that kicks off an AsyncTask.  The problem is, if the user rotates their display from portrait to landscape (or vice versa) while the AsyncTask is running, the AsyncTask is killed.  To fix the AsyncTask from stopping, I added the configChanges attribute to the AndroidManifest:

```
    <activity android:name="ListingFragment" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
```

However, adding that attribute then prevents the fragments from automatically switching to the landscape/portrait view.  Is there any way to have the fragments automatically switch their views without killing the AsyncTask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the instance of your asynctask before the activity gets killed. You can use [onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance%28%29) to save it. Then in your oncreate you can retrieve it using `getLastCustomNonConfigurationInstance()`. Then in your onCreate you can "attach" your activity to the asynctask again.

Comment: I think onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance() is deprecated and the documentation says to use setRetainInstance()

Comment: That's for a different purpose. If you call `setRetainInstance(true)` that means that the Fragment instance won't be destroyed with the activity, it will be retained (passed around), and the new activity will get this fragment instead of creating a new one.



Even though `onRetain...` IS deprecated, I don't know that they provided another way of keeping an instance of an object through activity destroy-create cycles.

Comment: good to know. I'll use onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance() then.  thanks for the response.

Comment: Also note that if you want to put your fragment on the backstack, you cant use setRetainInstance